# Properly return an error from a validation method

Tags: java

Supose I have a function to validate na input. It returns true when the input is valid and false otherwise.

Simple example:

```
public boolean validateEntry(Object entry){
    if(entry == null)
        return false;
    if(!(entry instanceof Entry.class))
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

Besides returning boolean, I also want to return the cause of invalidness.

My returning options are:

- Pair (java +1.8)
- Throws Exceptions
- Strings,
- Etc....

What is the proper way to return this function?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no ***proper*** (or standard) way; you must decide what is the most *appropriate* for your situation.

Answer (score 0):

I think one way **is to create a class like** `Error` **and return it**. (your function returns it)
As you know you can put all these attributes in it. e.g: `boolean`, `String`, etc.
also you can make different constructors for it, for different situations. also you can always return instead of it and check it in other side (when you call your function).
I think it is a good choice and I hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

I’d throw a custom runtime exception if the validation failed, you can have a different exception for each failed validation, then in your calling method surround around a try catch, catching the custom exception(s).

Comment: This is the approach Im doing on my code, but I am not 100% sure if it is a good one. 
Because this function is to verify if na entry is valid, so I think it needs to return something like true/false, not cast na Exception.